# IntelliSense for NodeJS OAuth library in VS Code

Tags: node.js, oauth, intellisense, visual-studio-code

First time using VS code and trying to get IntelliSense to work.

Here's what I've done:

Create and open a directory with VS code.

Add file package.json with content:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "oauth": "^0.9.13"
  }
}
```

`npm install` to retrieve oauth lib

Add file app.js with content (sample code):

```
/// <reference path='node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js' />
/// <reference path='node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js' />

var OAuth = require('oauth');

var OAuth2 = OAuth.OAuth2;    
var key = 'your key';
var secret = 'your secret';
var oauth2 = new OAuth2(
  key,
  secret, 
  'https://api.twitter.com/', 
  null,
  'oauth2/token', 
  null);

oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken(
  '',
  {'grant_type':'client_credentials'},
  function (e, access_token, refresh_token, results){
    console.log('bearer: ', access_token);
  });
```

Unfortunately I do not get any IntelliSense for the oauth library. I do get it when I type `console.`. Is there anything I'm missing or doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code uses TypeScript definition files even for JavaScript. Try adding [oauth.js.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/oauth.js/oauth.js.d.ts) to you project. Either use a ///-reference or create a jsconfig.json-file to mark a project: [JS in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript)

Comment: Thank you. I think oauth.js is a different library then the one I'm using (https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth), but I understand the idea.